# How to develop custom for loop helper to iterate over an array in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have designed a {{break}} custom helper which can be used to break the iteration in a custom for loop following a condition provided by if block. Please suggest how to create a custom for helper in handlebars.

```
<!-- required handlebars: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<!-- handlebars template: -->
<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

// NEED CUSTOM FOR HELPER HERE TO ITERATE THROUGH THE ARRAY SO THAT I CAN BREAK THE LOOP USING THE CUSTOM BREAK HELPER {{break}} ALREADY DESIGNED.


</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
//context object:
var context2 = ["student1","student2","student3","student4"];

//defining customized "break" helper in handlebars:
Handlebars.registerHelper("break", function(array, field, operator, breakvalue, options) {
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  var returnData="";
  var fieldValue = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      if (field === '.') {
        fieldValue=array[i];
      } else {
        fieldValue=array[i][field];
      }
      if ((operator == "eq" && fieldValue == breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "ne" && fieldValue != breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "gt" && fieldValue > breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "le" && fieldValue <= breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "ge" && fieldValue >= breakvalue) ||
          (operator == "lt" && fieldValue < breakvalue)) {
        returnData = returnData + options.fn(array[i]);
      } else {
        return  returnData;
      }
  }
  return  returnData;
});
//set variable template to handlebars-demo id in test.html:
var template = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
// Handlebars compiles the above template variable into a templateScript:
var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
// context object is passed to above templateScript:
var html = templateScript(context2);
//setting html to output:
$("#placeholder").append(html);

</script>
```

Comment: Any reason you prefer this over just filtering the source array before passing it to `Handlebars.compile()` ? Or using `{{#each}}{{#if ...}}...{{/if}}...{{/each}}` inside the template?

Comment: Can i use my custom break helper with {{#each}}{{#if ...}}...{{/if}}...{{/each}} ?? If yes, please show in the code.

Comment: Can i use custom helpers with built-in helpers inside handlebars template?

Comment: Else what would be the point of custom helpers if you could not combine them? Just try it! Our point is that you can express this logic with built-in helpers as well.

Comment: I have been trying to combine the custom break helper defined in above code with {{#each}}{{#if ...}}...{{/if}}...{{/each}}, but it is not working. Can u suggest the code? Suppose i have to break the loop at "student3" using {{#each}}{{#if ...}}...{{/if}}...{{/each}} and {{break}} in handlebars template?

Comment: How to define a custom for loop  in handlebars to iterate over an array?